# R ggplot2 geom_boxplot horizontal bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am very new to R and I wanted to use a box and whisker chart in my power bi dashboard and the custom visualisation for this was very slow for the volume of data.

I got the same data I am using in power bi from a mssql 2012 database and tried the same code in R studio. I get the box and whisker chart but all I get is horizontal bars. I am using the below code. SecondsOpen is still a num in the data frame as I had read this can get set to factor.

When I calculate median and average and percentiles via functions in power bi it all works ok. I am clearly doing something wrong but as I am so new to R I am struggling to see what.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(res,aes(month_start_date,'SecondsOpen')) +geom_boxplot()
```

Box and whisker Image
[image: Box and whisker Image]

Dataframe Datatypes Image
[image: Dataframe Datatypes Image]

Answer (score 0):

ah it was 'SecondsOpen' should be SecondsOpen!